# Import-Excel: Leading zeros and Ending Rows

Tags: powershell

I'm having 2 issues with Import-Excel. I am pulling three columns of data from another spreadsheet and creating a temp spreadsheet out of it.

1 - I have a column (Project No.) that is removing the leading zeros on the new spreadsheet. So Project No. 0600 will show as 600 in the new spreadsheet.

2 - The spreadsheet I am pulling the data from only has data up to XX row. The row may vary depending on how many projects are currently open. One month we could have 70 rows, the next we could have 80. However, when the new spreadsheet is created, it will add all the projects (which it should do) but it will also max out the number of rows under the last row (The table that is created has additional blank rows).

```
$path = "\\serverpath\Project Assignments.xlsm"

import-excel -path $path -WorksheetName "Assignments" -startrow 10 -startColumn 1 -headername "Project No.","Project Name","PM2","PM" | Select-Object "Project No.","Project Name","PM" | Export-Excel -NoNumberConversion "c:\test.xlsx"
```

Comment: Could you include a link to an example file?

Comment: @derekbaker783 example file that is created or that I am pulling data from?

Comment: An example of the file you're pulling data from.

Comment: https://kfriese-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/p/csmith/EcPky82jeatFuqVmRU9K85EBlkW8zFy2pB6r2Kw_m3E0Lw?e=ZJYjfe

Comment: This is Excel proper doing this since it is an int/number, not anything PowerShell is controlling, If you want leading zeros, take a look at these. [Excel using leading zeros](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Excel+using+leading+zeros&form=ANNTH1&refig=dffff0db689b43adb4e993ceec6510a9&sp=-1&pq=excel+using+leading+zero&sc=1-24&qs=n&sk=&cvid=dffff0db689b43adb4e993ceec6510a9)

Comment: @postanote Normally I would agree with you. However, I can pull folder names out of a directory and throw them into Excel and it keeps the leading zeros

get-childitem $Path -directory | select-object NAME | export-excel -tablename "Projects" -path c:\archive_$date.xlsx

Comment: Folder names are strings not ints, thus will be strings when brought into Excel or out of Excel. Yet, your post is pulling data from one Xls formatted file to another Xls formatted file, and on that, the Excel data import stuff Excel will work to help the data being inserted, format it and that is different than pulling string data from a text source like GCI.

Answer (score 1):

You can force Excel to not convert strings to numeric values by prefixing them with a TAB character.

Try:

```
$path = "\\serverpath\Project Assignments.xlsm"
Import-Excel -Path $path -WorksheetName "Assignments" -StartRow 10 -StartColumn 1 -HeaderName "Project No.","Project Name","PM2","PM" | 
Select-Object @{Name = "Project No."; Expression = { "`t{0}" -f $_."Project No."}}, "Project Name", "PM" | 
Export-Excel -NoNumberConversion "c:\test.xlsx"
```

If all your project numbers should have exactly 4 digits, prefixed with leading zeroes when needed, use:

```
@{Name = "Project No."; Expression = { "`t{0:D4}" -f $_."Project No."}}
```